# DropDown greyed out in Visual Studio Windows Forms (.Net Framework 4.8)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-4.8

I'm building a program in Windows Forms C#, in which you can choose between different options, and a DropDown component would be the perfect option, however for some reason it's greyed out and it doesn't let me use it.

I'm using the newest version of .NET framework 4.8, a lot of other components do work, and I could use a ComboBox for example, but the ideal option is still a DropDown.
I tried uninstalling VS and installing it again, restarting the toolbox multiple times, I even chose all the available packages when reinstalling, but I still can't select it, and I'm starting to think it's not even supported, but I just don't know.

[image: This is how a component I can use looks]

[image: And this is how all DropDown components look.]

Comment: Can you add what behaviour you are wanting/expecting from a `DropDownList` that doesn't exist or work for a `ComboBox`. I have always used the two term interchangeably. And, the `ComboBox` has a display option that sets it as a `DropDownList` - You can only set/select an option from the supplied list

Comment: i believe you must look up combobox, a Element DropDown doesn't exist since multiple years anymore, or you get an external Forms element,l also the last Dot Net Framework is 7.0 and soon 8.0

Comment: You're trying to use components that don't belong to WinForms. The ComboBox Control has a `DropDownStyle` property that allows to specify this functionality -- @nbk The last version of .NET Framework is 4.8.x (won't have any major updates ever) .NET (ex .NET Core) is at version 8 now. Don't mix the two

Answer (score 0):

I found DropDownList in ASP.Net Web Forms project, if you want to use it you must select ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) when creating the project.

[image]

After clicking Create, select Web Forms.

[image]

Then you can use DropDownList on the designer page.

[image]

There is no DropDown control or DropDownList control in Winforms, but you can use ComboBox. One property of the ComboBox control is DropDownStyle, which can be set to Simple, DropDown or DropDownList.

[image]